# React JS routing producing 404 error

Tags: reactjs

I am working with react js for routing my meteor application. It currently is producing an unusual (in my eyes) 404 routing error when working with a nested route.

My routing structure is as follows(I have removed some reference for readability:

```
  <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>

    <Route path="/" component={App}>

     <IndexRoute component={Home} />

      //Dashboard
      <Route path="app" component={AppDash}>

        <IndexRoute component={DashboardSummary} />

        <Route path="inbox" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Inbox} />
          <Route path="?query:query" component={App}/>
          <Route path=":id/confirm" component={Book}/>
          <Route path=":id" component={Conversation}/>
        </Route>

      </Route>
    </Route>

  </Router>
```

Now when I navigate to  `<Route path=":id/confirm" component={Book}/>` using  `<Link to={this.props.id + "/confirm"}>Book An Option</Link>` from within the **conversation** page I get a 404 error. However if I refresh on that link it brings up the correct page.

I'm not sure how I would debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Modifying below,

```
<Route path=":id/confirm" component={Book}/>
      <Route path=":id" component={Conversation}/>
```

to

```
 <Route path="confirm" component={Book}>
    <IndexRoute component={Book}/>
    <Route path=":id" component={Conversation}/>
  </Route>
```